# Append & Prepend Items masonry with imagesLoaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm trying to use this demo:

http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html

But i can't prepend and append new element.

```
$('#prepend').click(function(){
  var $boxes = $('<li><img src="/asset/images/8.jpg"/></li>');
  $('#container').prepend( $boxes ).masonry( 'reload' );
});

$('#append').click(function(){
  var $boxes = $('<li><img src="/asset/images/8.jpg"/></li>');
  $('#container').append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
});
```

new element don't display but it still alive in source.
Anyone can helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var boxes = '<li><img src="/asset/images/8.jpg"/></li>';
  // Get some more blocks
  $('#append').click(function(){
    // Append new blocks
    $container.append( boxes );
    // Have Masonry position new blocks
    $container.masonry( 'appended', boxes );
  });
```

Comment: My project with codeigniter framework: http://www.mediafire.com/download/e1ypa2udi2zm7mr/htdocs.rar